# Add SRID to Point

Tags: postgis, shapely, srid

When inserting a point into a PostGIS database I do it using

`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 1 2)',26918)`.

[image: in PgAdmin III I can see the SRID]

Note that this was done on a tutorial database where the SRID was set manually as explained [here](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/loading_data.html)

Now I try to do it in python, creating my own table *points*, but I don't know how to create it with the SRID that I want, so right now it hasn't any SRID set.
 Using the Shapely Point library, I create many points into a file and then `COPY points FROM file`

I create the points as `point = Point(0,1,2)` and then write the wkb_hex of this point into the file using `point.wkb_hex`. However, this doesn't contain any information on the SRID. so I tried using geoalchemy2 library as shown [here](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.6/shape.html)

```
point = Point(0,1,2)
wkb_element = from_shape(point, srid = 26918)
```

and then repeat the COPY FROM with the wkb_element from the file I stored it.
Unfortunately in my table I don't see any information on the SRID

[image]

Any hint on how to Add an SRID to my Shapely Point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the geoalchemy2 wkb_element is just an object that contains the srid, accessible as wkb_element.srid.
The SRID information should be updated in the column of the table by doing

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('points','geom',26918);
```

after you imported the data from the file. If you do it before you import the data, you would get an error

```
Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (26918)
```

since the imported Point doesn't contain the correct SRID, but only a default 0 value

However make sure that your geom column in the table was created as a 3 dimensional.

```
CREATE TABLE points (id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NULL,
                     geom GEOMETRY(PointZ) DEFAULT NULL)
```